# Disable Date Input Unless Selected Then Make Required

Tags: javascript, require

I am working on the following form that contains the following option values to select from.   If option value "Limited authorization for the following time period or visit date(s) listed below" is selected the `expdate` field is then enabled to be completed.    However, I would like to them make the `expdate` field required.    How can I achieve this?    I greatly appreciate any input or recommendations as I am not anywhere educated in this and have only learned by playing........

[image: Image of HTML Code If needed]

```js
<![CDATA[
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function $enableRequiredTextField($field) {
                            $field.val("");
                            $field.prop({"readonly": false,"tabIndex":0});
                            $field.removeAttr('style');
                        }

                        function $disableRequiredTextField($expdate) {
                            $field.val("N/A");
                            $field.prop({"readonly": true,"tabIndex":-1});
                            $field.css({"background-color": "#DDDDDD"});
                            $field.removeClass("alertborder");
                        }

                        $('#authorize').change(function() {//on change of select 
                          $('#expdate', ).prop('disabled', $('option:selected', this).val() != 'Limited authorization for the following time period or visit date(s) listed below');  
                          //check if value is not Limited authorization for the following time period or visit date(s) listed below then disable
                        }).change();//call on change manually so on load will run the change event
```

```html
        <inputField name="authorize" type="combo" prompt="Select an option from the drop down list:">
          <options>
            <option selected="true" />
            <option value="My authorization is not limited to a certain time period or visit date">My authorization is not limited to a certain time period or visit date</option>
            <option value="This authorization shall be in effect for 12 months following the date of signature">This authorization shall be in effect for 12 months following the date of signature</option>
            <option value="Limited authorization for the following time period or visit date(s) listed below">Limited authorization for the following time period or visit date(s) listed below</option>
          </options>
        </inputField>
        <inputField name="expdate" type="date" required="true" prompt="Date Authorized Until:" />
        <inputField name="mustCheck" type="checkbox">
          <options>
            <option value="true">I understand that this authorization will remain in effect until such time that I revoke it in writing.</option>
          </options>
        </inputField>
      </inputFields>
      <text type="submit" class="completeworkflow">Submit Request</text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the attached image I think you're referring to "mustCheck" right?
Try adding required to the inputField with name="mustCheck".

`<inputField name="mustCheck" type="checkbox" required>`

also html has an attribute called "disabled" so

```
<inputField name="expdate" type="date" required="true" disabled="true" prompt="Date Authorized Until:" />
```

and if you want to enable the element using JavaScript

`document.getElementById('expdate').disabled = false;`

if you're using jQuery

`$('#expdate').prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: I appreciate your help.  It would be the "expdate" that I want required when the "Limited" option is selected from "authorize".     I can get it to enable but I can not get it to be required once enabled.     I have tried putting the required in the input field, in the data element, etc. so thinking it bust be in the script somewhere that it needs to be called out.     Otherwise the mustCheck is missing that item and allowing them to submit the form.      Hopefully I explained that a bit better.    Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if having the element hidden or disabled has something to do with it not requiring. Maybe you could try changing the opacity to 0 instead of hiding it. It's a cheeky work around if it works but at least it would give us some insight on if that's the issue.